# Spring Boot ObjectMapper throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson-databind

I am currently working on an application that fails to run after upgrading to a newer snapshot version of a custom 3rd party dependency. Upon using this updated dependency I get the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'listener': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'objectMapper' defined in class path resource [com/****/****/****/WebMvcConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
 Failed to instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Factory method 'objectMapper' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The 'mapper' is what I am using locally, 'objectMapper' refers to a remote dependency. I realize this is may be challenging without code, but what could be causing this error? If I remove my objectmapper instance, the error only shifts to another section of the program, but the stack trace always leads to this:

```
Error creating bean with name 'objectMapper' defined in class path resource [com/****/****/****/WebMvcConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
 Failed to instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Factory method 'objectMapper' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Ive tried different versions of com.fasterxml.jackson.core but that does not seem to help. Any suggestions at all would be appreciated.

Edit:

Additional Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cashModule' defined in file 
[/Users/*****/******/*******/target/classes/*****/****/****/*****/cashModule.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'service5' defined in file 
[/Users/****/******/******/target/classes/****/****/*****/*****/EventProcessingService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'eventSource' defined in class path resource [com/****/****/****/******/EventConfig.class]:
 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'eventSource' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Source': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'bindingTargetFactories'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
 Error creating bean with name 'channelFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/stream/config/BinderFactoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'channelFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'compositeMessageChannelConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/stream/config/BinderFactoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'compositeMessageChannelConfigurer' parameter 0; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'messageConverterConfigurer' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/cloud/stream/config/BinderFactoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'messageConverterConfigurer' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'compositeMessageConverterFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/stream/config/ContentTypeConfiguration.class]: 
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.stream.converter.CompositeMessageConverterFactory]: Factory method 'compositeMessageConverterFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'objectMapper' defined in class path resource 
[com/****/****/*****/WebMvcConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Factory method 'objectMapper' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: looks like to me you create ObjectMapper as spring bean?

Comment: I originally was just autowiring in an objectMapper, changed to declaring a bean and still the same error

Comment: declare objectMapper as bean? still the same issue I think. Why you want it as bean? I don't know if that could work either

Comment: Im really just autowiring it in.

Comment: Don't autowire ObjectMapper as spring bean. Just create it as variable. Try that & see if it still error

Comment: That did get rid of the initial error, but like I said the error just moves to another area. And  the stack trace leads to the same thing

Comment: If it leads to the same thing then I think there's something wrong in the beans declaration. Can you put the full stack trace?

Comment: I added the stack trace after removing Autowire from objectMapper

Comment: Why your cashModule.class name is cashModule not CashModule? In my opinion it could be issue while using it as spring bean

Comment: it is actually CashModule in the stack trace, that was mistake on my part when putting in ****

Comment: I think you could try upgrading your spring also. "upgrading to a newer snapshot version of a custom 3rd party dependency" the 3rd party dependency is using spring? Still the error seem to come from WebMvcConfig. Is that class in 3rd party dependency?

Comment: Yes the class causing the error is coming from that dependency

Comment: The error come when start web server? How do u run it? maven build or ... ? some silly solution but once works for me is changing the order of the dependencies

Comment: Mvn clean install. when I skip the tests it builds successfully, however when I run i get the same error as above. Its strange because the same dependecy is used across multiple applications however they all run fine. I can not seem to find the issue. I appreciate all the help